# How can the login greeter drums be turned off in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: sound, 15.10, unity-greeter

I want to disable the startup sound effects that play when the login greeter appears after booting Ubuntu 15.10. How can this be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With one command in your terminal, disable with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter play-ready-sound "false"
```

and/or enable with

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter play-ready-sound "true"
```

---

Or install `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

and run

```
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to

```
com.canonical.unity-greeter
```

in the left pane. In the right pane you will see `play-ready-sound`

and you could do the same in a GUI.

Comment: Although gsettings command worked (I was able to set from true to false), nothing changed. I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. Can it be the cause? After a restart, the drum roll still there. Should the command be run with a special user? If yes, how?